# Sorting objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-8

I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList` by two criterias: ascending in both row and col. I'm getting the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    - The method RowColElem() is undefined for the type 
     DenseBoard<T>
    - The method RowColElem() is undefined for the type 
     DenseBoard<T>
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
public class DenseBoard<T>{

    private ArrayList<RowColElem<T>> tempDiagList;

    public void foo() {
        Collections.sort(tempDiagList, Comparator.comparingInt(RowColElem::getRow())
                                                 .thenComparingInt(RowColElem::getCol()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the parenthesis at `RowColElem::getRow()` and `RowColElem::getCol()`.

Comment: Still the same. I did `RowColElem::getRow` and `RowColElem::getCol` but sill getting errors.  `Multiple markers at this line
 - RowColElem cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
  tokens
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
  tokens
 - RowColElem cannot be resolved to a 
  variable`

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with Java 8? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @Tunaki, yes Im using Java 8

Comment: Then try to reduce your example to a minimal one. There's too much code in your post.

Comment: @Tunaki done. Btw my java version is 1.8.0_31. Is it ok?

Comment: I edited your post to remove all the unnecessary code so that it is easier to see the real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem with your code comes from the extra parentheses in `RowColElem::getRow()` and `RowColElem::getCol()`. This is called a method reference ([section 15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) of the JLS for the details).

Then, the real issue here is that the Java compiler cannot infer the correct type of the element in the lambda expression of `comparingInt` and it defaults to `Object`.

You have to specify the type of the expected element like this:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.<RowColElem<T>> comparingInt(RowColElem::getRow)
                                                 .thenComparingInt(RowColElem::getCol));
```

Another solution would be to use a local assignment:

```
Comparator<RowColElem<T>> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(RowColElem::getRow);
List<RowColElem<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list, comparator.thenComparingInt(RowColElem::getCol));
```

Comment: I hate saying this but its giving me the same very error. It says RowColElem cannot be assigned to a variable, @Tunaki

Comment: Did you copy the first snippet of code without typo? I just tested and it works.

Comment: No need to use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` in Java-8. Just call `list.sort(comparator)`.